# What is alternative to jQuery(this) in YUI 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I have started coding in yui and already have good knowledge of jQuery ,

I need some information about migrating from jQuery to yui.

What is the alternative to jQuery(this) in YUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases, jQuery(this) is done inside event callbacks to wrap the subscribed element with the jQuery API.  In YUI3, that's done for you automatically.  The `this` in event callbacks is the Node instance that was subscribed from.

```
Y.one('#readygo').on('click', function (e) {
    this.append("<p><code>this</code> is already a YUI 3 wrapped Node instance.</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You may find [JS Rosettastone](http://www.jsrosettastone.com/) useful. I found it invaluable when I moved to YUI 3 and I will not move back.